# Pass arguments into backbone .bind() function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a view that renders a video player and a video list.

```
initialize: function() {
var q = window.location.search.slice(3);
this.videos = new Videos(window.exampleVideoData);
this.videos.bind('select', this.notifyAppView, this);
if ( q ){
  this.videos.bind('fetchFinished', function(){
      console.log('should still work');
      this.render();
  }, this);
  // Any time this.videos collection changes we will re-render
  this.videoPlaying = this.videos.models[0];
  this.videos.fetch( q );
}else{
  //Collection of all videos

  // Any time this.videos collection changes we will re-render
  this.videoPlaying = this.videos.models[0];
  this.render();
}
```

},

That is my initialize function on the view. The problem that I am getting is that when I pass in arguments into the bind function , the error

```
app.js:10 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

That is the line :

```
this.videos.bind('fetchFinished', function(){
  console.log('should still work');
  this.render();
```

}, this);

We get the error when we pass in a string to the function like so, :

```
this.videos.bind('fetchFinished', function('adfadf'){
      console.log('should still work');
      this.render();
}, this);
```

What is the correct way to specify a function to be bound with backbone, that takes an argument?

Answer (score 2):

That is incorrect syntax. You should specify the argument's name in function declaration, not the value.

You can pass in a value like this:

```
this.videos.bind('fetchFinished', function(arg){
  console.log('should still work', arg); // should still work adfadf
  this.render();
}.bind(this, 'adfadf'));
```

Note that the second `bind` is native `bind` method of function objects, not the backbone `bind`. It'd be better to use backbone's `on` instead of using it's alias `bind` to avoid confusion